# SUM of columns and displaying multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table: MyTable

[image]

and I need to display the following data:
productLine
buyPrice
MSRP

both buyPrice and MSRP need to use SUM for their data and be indexed by productLine so the output will look as follows:

**productLine**

Planes
Ships
 Trains
 Trucks and Boats

**buyPrice**
SUM of all values in buyPrice per productLine

**MSRP**
SUM of all values in MSRP per productLine

Im using the following query wothout any success:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(buyPrice) FROM myTable, SELECT SUM(MSRP) FROM myTable, SELECT * FROM myTable"); // selecting data through mysql_query()
```

and here is my conditional

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['productLine'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";  

echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['SUM(buyPrice)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>"; 
}  

echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['SUM(MSRP)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</table>";
```

Im not getting any output whatsoever. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot execute multiple queries in mysql_query function

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(buyPrice) AS sum_buy_price, SUM(MSRP) AS sum_msrp FROM myTable");`

Comment: #Tamil Selvan's answer looks good. Just slighly modify it to get all the data by `productLine`:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(buyPrice) AS sum_buy_price, SUM(MSRP) AS sum_msrp FROM myTable GROUP BY `productLine`");

Comment: Thanks for the hep! In the end I used a combination of all of the feedback given here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT productLine, SUM(buyPrice) AS sum_buy_price, SUM(MSRP) AS sum_msrp FROM myTable group by productLine"); // selecting data through mysql_query()
```

and to output the results:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['productLine'] . "</td>";  
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['sum_buy_price'] . "</td>";  
    echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['sum_msrp'] . "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Mike. It worked as given.